# paypal service not start in android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, noclassdeffounderror

I have integrated paypal payment gateway with following details:

In my activity start paypal service as using below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
startService(intent);
```

Once the activity is being execute ... It crashed.. and following are the error log of my android studio:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:364)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.cc.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2688)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

And in my gradle file i have used following gradle libraries in my project gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2') {
        //exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
        exclude group: 'junit'  // junit:junit-dep conflicts with junit:unit
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'se.simbio.encryption:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    // Loader
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev171-1.22.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    //compile files('libs/mediaplayersdk.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

}
```

The same code of paypal integration is working in sample application.
Can anyone has any suggestion or solution related to this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `okhttp` is a dependency for the Paypal SDK, so try to add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
```

Comment: I have checked with it.. not solved with this solution.

Comment: You're still having the exact same issue?

Comment: Yes the same issue